# How to check if a set of strings contains another string, without using any function?

Tags: python, string, set

lately, I had started using sets in my code, and I was wondering how to know if a string is inside other string making use of only `sets` instead of the iterable function `any` the example I came up with is something like this

```py
    set1 = set({"nb","np"})
    word = "rainbow"
    if any(i in word for i in set1):
        print("not a spanish word")
    else:
        print("probably a spanish word")
```

so if the set1 increases in elements (like adding an "mm"), then it will affect the time spent because of the increase of iterations of the function `any`, and if you make a set of `word` the information of the order of the letters is lost because the elements of that new set will be the letters of the word, in which case you won't know if the strings in set1 are actually inside the word, or at least that's what I think.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to do it without the function any

Comment: you want to do it without `any` because you think it is inefficient? I'm pretty sure you won't get much better since the actual complexity can't be lowered by much.

Comment: is not that I think that any is inefficient, but I think there should be a way to do the same, making use of sets only

Comment: Based on the [Python documentation of `any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), `any()` will return as soon as an iterable yields a true element (i.e., it short-circuits), so it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: @jjramsey: Then shouldn't the result always be the same regardless of what is in `word`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Based on my misinterpretation of the code (which I've since deleted, because it was wrong), yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's said in the comments, `any` will be better in any case, but if you only want to use sets, this could be an approach:

```
set1 = set({"nb","np"})
word = "rainbow"
slicedword=set([word[i:i+2]for i in range(len(list(word))-1)])
if len(slicedword.intersection(set1))>=1:
    print("not a spanish word")
else:
    print("probably a spanish word")
```

**General solution** *(for different lengths of `set1`'s elements)*

```
set1 = set({"nb","np","mmm"})
word = "rainbow"
for i in set1:
    n=len(i)
    slicedword=set([word[i:i+n]for i in range(len(list(word))-(n-1))])
    print(slicedword)
    if len(slicedword.intersection(set1))>=1:
        print("not a spanish word")
        break
else:
    print("probably a spanish word")
```

---

**Explanation:**

First, we slice `word` into chunks of the size of the substring of `set1`, which in this case will be 2 for all words in set1:

```
set1 = set({"nb","np"})
word="rainbow"
slicedword=set([word[i:i+2]for i in range(len(list(word))-1)])
slicedword
>>>{'in', 'ow', 'ra', 'bo', 'nb', 'ai'}
```

Then you do `set.intersection` and evaluate if the length of the intersection is equal or greater than 1, which means you have at least one match.

```
slicedword.intersection(set1)
>>>{'nb'}

len(slicedword.intersection(set1))
>>>1

len(slicedword.intersection(set1))>=1
>>>True
```

Comment: it seems that the iterative process is inevitable either using any or for. but I guess the creation of a set is an iterative process itself, so I wonder if having a custom function that creates sets of strings with elements of custom lengths just as you did, would be something worth to add in python.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure, you will have to use an iterative proccess in any option, I think. And sure, you could create a custom function to return the chunked word, that will make cleaner the code, in fact, there are libraries that make that proccess of chunk the string, if I'm not bad. But for me, you original solution it's the best way to do what you want.